Upper bound on diameter of overlapping rectangles
Let $e,e'\in S^1$, where $S^1$ denotes the unit circle, and let $T_e^\delta(a)$ and $T_{e'}^\delta(b)$ be tubes (or rectangles) in $\mathbb{R}^2$ centered at $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ pointing in the directions $e$ and $e'$ respectively with width $2\delta$ and length 1. Specifically, the direction of the tube is parallel to the side of length 1. Why is it that for some constant $C>0$,
$\begin{align}
diameter (T_e^\delta(a)\cap T_{e'}^\delta(b))\leq C\frac{\delta}{arccos(e\cdot e')+\delta}
\end{align}$?
I have come to this problem from some lecture notes I am reading on the Kakeya conjecture: https://people.math.rochester.edu/faculty/iosevich/expository/seminarlecture2.pdf (see 4.3). Apparently this is not so hard to show, but I don't see it.
I believe that the case where the tubes overlap the most is when $a=b$, and when this occurs we have 2 cases:

If $arccos(e\cdot e')$, ie the angle between $e$ and $e'$, is far enough away from $\pi$ and $0$, then the overlapping region is a parallelogram where all sides have length greater than $2\delta$ (from triangle inequality). Due to the orientations of the tubes, there are 2 angles that are $arccos(e\cdot e')$. From here I try to get an upper bound on the lengths of the diagonals using the law of cosines but I don't get anything that looks like the inequality I am trying to prove.
(edit: replace $\delta$ with $2\delta$ because I misinterpreted the definition of a tube originally)
If $arccos(e\cdot e')$ is close to $\pi$ or $0$, then the overlapping region has 6 sides that I don't know how to describe with words. I ran into trouble drawing this clearly.

Perhaps the tubes overlapping a lot does not maximize the diameter of the overlap however, and I am going down the wrong route.
